# Use dynamic div IDs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a container which is filled with max. 20 items, each item gets its information (such as image) from an SQL database and an own div with id `suit_(1-20)`.

The items get listed in the code below:

```
<?php 
    $d = 1;
?>
<table >
    <tbody>
    <?php while $item = sqlsrv_fetch_object($user_item) : ?>
        <td align="center" height="50" width="21%">
            <div class="tooltips" href="">
                <div class="suitable" id="suit_<?php echo $d++ ?>" name="<?php echo $myDBID ?>">
                    <img src="images/icon/<?php echo $item->Img ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>   
    <?php endwhile; ?>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you see each div has the id `suit_(d++)` which means 1-20 for max 20 items.
Those divs have a jQuery script to trigger a contextual menu event on right click:

```
$(function () {
    var count;
    for(count = 1; count < 21; count++) {
        var ID = document.getElementById('suit_' + count).getAttribute('id');
        $('#suit_' + count).contextPopup({
            items : [{
                label : 'Set',
                action : function () {
                    window.location.href = "?settest=" + ID
                }
            },
            null, 
            {
                label : 'Throw',
                action : function () {
                    window.location.href = "?throwtest=" + ID
                }
            },
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

I have a for-loop which should count from 1 to 20 and generate the appropriate ids (`suit_1` to `suit_20`).

Somehow the script works only for the last item in the container, so if I have 10 items in it, all items will get the ID `suit_10`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why not remove the loop, and use an [starts with attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)?

Using the `^=` selector says "anything that starts with":

```
// A bit "safer" document ready, won't collide with other libraries that use $
jQuery(function($) {
    // Select all items with ID starting with "suit_"
    $('[id^="suit_"]').contextPopup({
        items : [{
            label : 'Set',
            action : function () {
                window.location.href = "?settest=" + $(this).attr('id');
            }
        },
        null, 
        {
            label : 'Throw',
            action : function () {
                window.location.href = "?throwtest=" + $(this).attr('id');
            }
        },
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: This is actually pretty nice and will be helpful in the further project, sadly the entire dropdown stops working if i use this selector.
I also tried $( div'[id^="suit_"]') like mentioned on the site you just refered to, the problem still remains.

Comment: I noticed now the selector works like a charm, the actual problem is the
"var ID = $(this).attr('id');"
inside the event handler.
If i remove it the dropdown works fine, but outside i have the same problem like before.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue.  Standby.

Comment: Thanks for hanging on. Sadly i went through this issue already a few times today. I changed my code with your edits and at least the dropdown works again, but somehow the actual div container ID is not recognized, as i get "?settest=undefined" onclick on the menu button. Also $(event.target) shows the same result.

Comment: Hm.  It may seem that the contextPopup function is taking control of the "this" - without diving into that code, this becomes more complicated.  My solution may not work, it may be that you need your loop afterall (which is lame, I think).  Question - in your own code, why not make the var ID call like this: `var ID = 'suit_' + count;` ? That may help?

Comment: You are right, the contextPopup function avoids the setting of a variable inside the function. After i added the each(function()) and set the variable between that and the event handler the script works just fine (See my answer above) Thanks again for not giving up.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding an `each(function())` for the selector and setting a variable `object` before the event starts.

The problem with the previous solution was the child function

```
action : function () {
   window.location.href = "?settest=" + ID
}
```

which caused that `$(this)`was not working.

See the full code below:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('[id^="suit_"]').each(function(){
    var object = this;
    $(object).contextPopup({
        items : [{
            label : 'Set',
            action : function () {
                window.location.href = "?settest=" + object.id
            }
        },
        null, 
        {
            label : 'Throw',
            action : function () {
                window.location.href = "?throwtest=" + object.id
            }
        },
        ]
    });
    });
});
```